# Magento 2 JS Merge Undeifned Varaible Issue

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript

I have defined admin form field dependency in my **uicomponent** form

```
<field name="redirect_in">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Namespace\Modulename\Model\Config\Source\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">int</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store Info</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Modulename/js/form/element/options</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">modulename</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">redirect_in</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
<field name="storeviews">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">int</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store View</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">modulename</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">redirect_store_id</item>
            <item name="visibleValue" xsi:type="string">0</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>                        
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
<field name="external_url">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">External Link</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">modulename</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">redirect_external_url</item>
            <item name="visibleValue" xsi:type="string">1</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>                        
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="validate-url" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

The dependent js to get and reterive the value

> Namespace\Modulename\Model\Config\Source\Options

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function (_, uiRegistry, select, modal) {
    'use strict';

    return select.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            var storeviewField = uiRegistry.get('index = storeviews');
            var externalUrl = uiRegistry.get('index = external_url');
            if(this.value() == 1){
                externalUrl.show();
                storeviewField.hide();
            } else {
                storeviewField.show();
                externalUrl.hide();
            }

            return this;
        },

    });
});
```

This works great until I merge JS from magento setting.

I get the following error

> storeviewField undifined

Why is it causing issue when I merge the JS Files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue I moved my column above.

Try moving your `storeviews` column above `redirect_in`:

```
<field name="storeviews">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">int</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store View</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">modulename</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">redirect_store_id</item>
            <item name="visibleValue" xsi:type="string">0</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
<field name="external_url">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">External Link</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">modulename</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">redirect_external_url</item>
            <item name="visibleValue" xsi:type="string">1</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="validate-url" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
<field name="redirect_in">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Namespace\Modulename\Model\Config\Source\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">int</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store Info</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Modulename/js/form/element/options</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">modulename</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">redirect_in</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```